# Nextflow name collision

Tags: nextflow

I have files with identical names but in different folders. Nextflow stages these files into the same work directory resulting in name collisions. My question is how to deal with that **without** renaming the files. Example:

```bash
# Example data
mkdir folder1 folder2
echo 1 > folder1/file.txt
echo 2 > folder2/file.txt

# We read from samplesheet
$ cat samplesheet.csv
sample,file
sample1,/home/atpoint/foo/folder1/file.txt
sample1,/home/atpoint/foo/folder2/file.txt

# Nextflow main.nf
#! /usr/bin/env nextflow

nextflow.enable.dsl=2

// Read samplesheet and group files by sample (first column)
samplesheet = Channel
    .fromPath(params.samplesheet)
    .splitCsv(header:true)
    .map {
            sample = it['sample']
            file   = it['file']
            tuple(sample, file)
}
        
ch_samplesheet = samplesheet.groupTuple(by:0)

// That creates a tuple like:
// [sample1, [/home/atpoint/foo/folder1/file.txt, /home/atpoint/foo/folder2/file.txt]]

// Dummy process that stages both files into the same work directory folder
process PRO {

    input:
    tuple val(samplename), path(files)

    output:
    path("out.txt")

    script:
    """
    echo $samplename with files $files > out.txt
    """

}

workflow { PRO(ch_samplesheet) }

# Run it
NXF_VER=21.10.6 nextflow run main.nf --samplesheet $(realpath samplesheet.csv)
```

...obviously resulting in:

```
N E X T F L O W  ~  version 21.10.6
Launching `main.nf` [adoring_jennings] - revision: 87f26fa90b
[-        ] process > PRO -
Error executing process > 'PRO (1)'

Caused by:
  Process `PRO` input file name collision -- There are multiple input files for each of the following file names: file.txt
```

So, what now? The real world application here is sequencing replicates of the same fastq file, which then have the same name, but are in different folders, and I want to feed them into a process that merges them. I am aware of this [section in the docs](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/process.html#multiple-input-files) but cannot say that any of it was helpful or that I understand it properly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `stageAs` option in your process definition.

```
#! /usr/bin/env nextflow
nextflow.enable.dsl=2

samplesheet = Channel
    .fromPath(params.samplesheet)
    .splitCsv(header:true)
    .map {
        sample = it['sample']
        file = it['file']
        tuple(sample, file)
     }
    .groupTuple()
    .set { ch_samplesheet }

// [sample1, [/path/to/folder1/file.txt, /path/to/folder2/file.txt]]

process PRO {
    input:
        tuple val(samplename), path(files, stageAs: "?/*")

    output:
        path("out.txt")

    shell:
        def input_str = files instanceof List ? files.join(" ") : files
        """
        cat ${input_str} > out.txt
        """
}

workflow { PRO(ch_samplesheet) }
```

See [an example from nf-core](https://github.com/nf-core/modules/blob/3a1919641c75a83d8b12a43d907b318f694f04b0/modules/nf-core/biobambam/bamsormadup/main.nf#L9) and the [`path` input type docs](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/process.html#input-type-path)

Comment: More information about the stageAs option in the official documentation: https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/process.html